# Resample pandas dataframe by both name and origin

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have the following Pandas DataFrame object `df`. It is a train schedule listing the date of departure, scheduled time of departure, and train company.

```
import pandas as pd
df = 

            Year  Month DayofMonth  DayOfWeek  DepartureTime Train    Origin
Datetime
1988-01-01  1988    1     1         5        1457      BritishRail   Leeds
1988-01-02  1988    1     2         6        1458      DeutscheBahn  Berlin
1988-01-03  1988    1     3         7        1459      SNCF           Lyons
1988-01-02  1988    1     2         6        1501      BritishRail   Ipswich
```

Now, I would like to resample this time series by listing for each week the number of times a certain rail company departed from this station by origin.

For instance, how many British Rail trains leave this station per week? How many British Rail trains leave this station per week originating from Leeds?

I suspected the result to be a pandas series object.

I tried for total British Rails per week

```
BR_weekly = df[df['Train']=='BritishRail'].resample("W", how='sum')
```

but this does not give me a time series of the form

```
Datetime   Number of trains
i.e.
Datetime
1988-01-03     434
1988-01-10     982
1988-01-17     989
Freq: W-SUN, dtype: int64
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My input data (add and change some date):

```
print df
            Year  Month  DayofMonth  DayOfWeek  DepartureTime         Train  \
Datetime                                                                      
1988-01-01  1988      1           1          5           1457   BritishRail   
1988-01-01  1988      1           1          5           1457   BritishRail   
1988-01-10  1988      1           2          6           1458  DeutscheBahn   
1988-01-12  1988      1           3          7           1459          SNCF   
1988-01-20  1988      1           2          6           1501   BritishRail   

             Origin  
Datetime             
1988-01-01    Leeds  
1988-01-01    Leeds  
1988-01-10   Berlin  
1988-01-12    Lyons  
1988-01-20  Ipswich
```

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html)and count values of column `Train`.

```
print df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W'))['Train'].count()
1988-01-03    2
1988-01-10    1
1988-01-17    1
1988-01-24    1
Freq: W-SUN, Name: Train, dtype: int64
```

Or you can select column `Train` and [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.resample.html) it by `count`:

```
print df['Train'].resample('W', how='count')
Datetime
1988-01-03    2
1988-01-10    1
1988-01-17    1
1988-01-24    1
Freq: W-SUN, Name: Train, dtype: int64
```

EDIT:

I think you cannot use `sum`, because it concatenate strings in column `Train`:

```
print df.Train[df['Train'].isin(['BritishRail'])].resample("W", how='sum')
Datetime
1988-01-03    BritishRailBritishRail
1988-01-10                         0
1988-01-17                         0
1988-01-24               BritishRail
Freq: W-SUN, Name: Train, dtype: object
```

Select one column `Train`, where is `BritishRail` using [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and resample it with `count` instead of `sum`:

```
print df.Train[df['Train'].isin(['BritishRail'])].resample("W", how='count')
Datetime
1988-01-03    2
1988-01-10    0
1988-01-17    0
1988-01-24    1
Freq: W-SUN, Name: Train, dtype: int64
```

Comment: That works. I believe the '.isin()' method works the best. Thanks!

Comment: You might be able to help with this problem I am having: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34401244/how-to-use-pandas-series-to-plot-two-time-series-of-different-lengths-starting-d?noredirect=1#comment56546040_34401244