# How to use Pandas Series to plot two Time Series of different lengths/starting dates?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I am plotting several pandas series objects of "total events per week". The data in the series `events_per_week` looks like this:

```
Datetime
 1995-10-09     45
 1995-10-16     63
 1995-10-23     83
 1995-10-30     91
 1995-11-06    101 
Freq: W-SUN, dtype: int64
```

My problem is as follows. All pandas series are the same length, i.e. beginning in same year 1995. One array begins in 2003 however. `events_per_week2003` begins in 2003

```
 Datetime
     2003-09-08     25
     2003-09-15     36
     2003-09-22     74
     2003-09-29     25
     2003-09-05    193 
    Freq: W-SUN, dtype: int64

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))
ax = plt.subplot(111)
plt.plot(events_per_week)
plt.plot(events_per_week2003)
```

I get the following value error.

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: you could extract each column into a variable and then plot(x,y). What is `events_per_week` in your code? A Series?

Comment: @tglaria 'events_per_week' is a series beginning in 1995.

Comment: @tglaria I do not understand this "you could extract each column into a variable and then plot(x,y)"

Comment: What I meant is to store column 1 as an array on dates, store column 2 as an array of float and then `plot(column 1, column 2)`, although I'm sure there is a direct way of plotting it.

Comment: ok, you could plot with `events_per_week.plot('Datetime', 'name_of_other_column')` and then `plt.show()`

Comment: @tglaria `event_per_week` is an array of 1100 weeks, 1995 to today. `event_per_week2003` is a fraction of this. I am not sure I am following...

Comment: I don't get what you want to do and why you can't. Could you upload a piece of your source file (like 10 lines or so), and the code you're using to load it so I could try to replicate?

Answer (score 3):

I really don't get where you're having problems.
I tried to recreate a piece of the dataframe, and it plotted with no problems.

```
import numpy, matplotlib
data = numpy.array([45,63,83,91,101])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=pd.date_range('2005-10-09', periods=5, freq='W'), columns=['events'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(numpy.arange(10,21,2), index=pd.date_range('2003-01-09', periods=6, freq='W'), columns=['events'])
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(df1.index, df1.events)
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(df2.index, df2.events)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Using Series instead of Dataframe:

```
ds1 = pd.Series(data, index=pd.date_range('2005-10-09', periods=5, freq='W'))
ds2 = pd.Series(numpy.arange(10,21,2), index=pd.date_range('2003-01-09', periods=6, freq='W'))
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(ds1)
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(ds2)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Comment: The problem is that the series `event_per_weeks` is a much longer array than `event_per_weeks2003`. So, there must be some way to plot both.

Comment: See the above. `event_per_weeks` is a time series of 1100 weeks, as it is from 1995-present. `event_per_weeks2003` is a time series of approximately 500 weeks. There is a ValueError when plotting both simultaneously.

Comment: There's maybe an error in your original file? Could you upload it? I'm plotting two dataframes, no problem.

Comment: That could be my problem. I'm using pandas series, not data frames.

Comment: I tried the same thing with data Series and I get no error (although I have no   horizontal axis date).